# How to Configure Jasper Server with Oracle Database instead of postgresql and mysql?

Tags: oracle, docker, ubuntu-16.04, jasperserver

I am trying to connect the JasperReports-server with oracle database using docker file. but JasperReports-server has an option that by default, we can connect with MySQL and PostgreSQL databases. Now we want to connect JasperReports-server with oracle database. For that, we wrote Dockerfile and trying to build the image. we were unable to build the jasper server image and got the build failed error, because of db.template.properties file.

here is the snapshot of the error message

[image]

so, how can I get the oracle database-related configuration files as like MySQL and  Postgresql?

Could anybody suggest me to resolve this error?

Comment: What edition of JasperServer do you use? If JasperServer CE than you have just Postgres and MySQL. Other databases supported only in PRO version.

Comment: hello @V. Spachynskyi. I am using 6.4.2.

Comment: The version is 6.4.2. But what the edition Community or PRO? Also in the root of the project, you should have a docs folder where you can find Install Guide. There are chapter how to set up other databases.